# Why is my code making duplicates in zipfile

Tags: python, zip

I'm struggling with this code. Every time, it's giving me a zipfile with a bunch of duplicates. Is there any easy solution for that?

The `namelist` part is my latest idea to resolve this issue, but it still doesn't work.

```
import os, time, zipfile
from os.path import basename

path = 'c:\\Users\\laptop'



def find(type, archname):
    files = []
    # r=root, d=directories, f = files
    starttime = time.time()
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            if '.'+type in file:
                files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

    zipp=zipfile.ZipFile('c:\\Users\\laptop\\backup\\'+archname+'.zip', 'w')
    zipfiles=[]
    zipfiles=zipp.namelist()

    for f in files:
        file=basename(f)
        if file in zipfiles:
            print('Element skipped')
        else:
            zipp.write(f, basename(f))
    zipp.close()

    print('\nTime: ' + str(round(time.time() - starttime, 2)) + 's')
    print('Files found: ' + str(len(files)))
print('Enter type: ')
typ=input()
print('Enter zip name: ')
archname=input()
find(typ, archname)
print('Done.')
```

Comment: what are the duplicates that you are getting

Comment: is it ever printing 'Element skipped'? try printing both zipfiles and basename(f), maybe there's some sort of difference that is causing the duplicates

Comment: I tried to run your code, its running properly. I am able to create a single zip file containing all the .txt files in the path provided, without any duplicates.

Comment: @Jeril: Sometimes i have same pdf in multiple directories (like downloaded and moved few times) and I want to get only unique pdfs in archive.

Comment: @Gamopo No, i have only "UserWarning: Duplicate name: " warning and multiple duplicated files inside zip

Comment: @AnupamChaplot: It's probably because you dont have same names of a files in there

Comment: Then it seems to me that the condition `if file in zipfiles:` is never true, try printing each element and check why it's not working when it should, probably as I said before, there are some mismatch in both names lists

Comment: @Llit, I checked again I have 5 files with name __init__.py in the zip file.

Comment: @Gamopo: Do you have any other idea how to make list of unique files? imo zipfile.namelist() is not the answer

Answer (score 1):

Below is Python code that adds a file to a zip archive only if the file does not exist within the archive. Set a new file exists flag (blnNewFNExists) because you need to check the archive first and close it (automatically when using `with`) before adding the file (newFN) to the archive.

```
newFN=MyNewFile.jpg
blnNewFNExists = False
# check that the file you are trying to add to the zip file does not already exist in the archive
with zipfile.ZipFile('/MyImages/archive/Example.zip') as zf:
    if newFN in zf.namelist():
        blnNewFNExists=True   # this tells us the file exists in the zip

# if the new file does not exist in the zip file then we add it
if blnNewFNExists == False:
    zipfile.PyZipFile('/MyImages/archive/Example.zip', 'a') as myzip:
        myzip.write('/DirectoryOfTheNewFile/'+newFN, newFN)
        print('adding file ',newFN) # test print statement
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code already, I think the problem is you are opening it with write mode, so `zipp.namelist()` is returning an empty string. Change

```
zipp=zipfile.ZipFile('c:\\Users\\laptop\\backup\\'+archname+'.zip', 'w')
```

for

```
zipp=zipfile.ZipFile('c:\\Users\\comun\\Pictures\\'+archname+'.zip', 'a')
```

and it should work. You should start to see 'Element skipped' in the console. I hope it helps.

Comment: Didn't work. I changed it and nothing happened and in zipfile there are same amount of duplicates like before. I need to find another way

Comment: could you share an example of how you're executing it and the result you're getting? You could also try to refresh the namelist after each insertion, that would increase the severity of the analysis but it should work without that as well

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `zipp.write(f, basename(f))` which just return filename, so everything is in one single directory, so same filename will even though in different directory will be a duplicate when you add it to the zip file.

You can use `os.path.relpath(f,'c:\\Users\\laptop')` instead of basename, it will then be relative to `c:\\Users\\laptop`